# KendoUI grid with dropdown column + angular

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, grid

I would like to have KendoUI grid where one of the columns is a dropdown-list. 
the dropdown list is loaded from an odata controller.
I would like to do it with angularjs.

can anyone lead me?

thanks,
Hagai

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873490/using-templateseditors-in-grid-column-with-angular-kendo-ui

Answer (score -1):

Grid / Editing custom editor on Telerik

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom